# What is the most elegant way to implement GetTextAfterMarker()

Tags: c#, string, refactoring

Here is another old function I have from my C# 1 days, what would be a more elegant way to write it:

```
//method: gets the text in a string in front of a marker, if marker is not there, then return empty string
//example: GetTextAfterMarker("documents/jan/letter043.doc","/") returns "documents"
//example: GetTextAfterMarker("letter043.doc","/") returns ""
//rank:8
public static string GetTextAfterMarker(string line, string marker)  {
    string r = "";

    int pos = line.IndexOf(marker);
    if(pos != -1) {
        r = line.Substring(pos+(marker.Length),line.Length-pos-(marker.Length));
    } else {
        r = "";
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in your code. Using pos+(marker.Length) as the starting position for Substring is going to start after the marker, and will return, in your first example, "jan/letter043.doc". So either your code has a bug or you've named the function wrong.

Comment: sorry, the function name is wrong but Fredrik Mörk helped me to write it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172216/how-can-i-refactor-this-c-code-using-split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the name somewhat strange, given that it should return the text appearing *before* the first marker. But this one does the same job, I think (I took the liberty to change the name):

```
public static string GetTextBeforeMarker(string line, string marker)
{
    if (line == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("line");
    }

    if (marker == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("marker");
    }

    string result = line.Split(new string[] { marker }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
    return line.Equals(result) ? string.Empty : result;
}
```

Explanation: split the string into an array using the marker as split argument. If the first element of the result is the same as the input, the marker was not in the string, so we return an empty string, otherwise we return the first element (which is the text up to the first occurrence of the marker).

Comment: That's a nice use of Split(), I used to create GetTextAfterMarker here, but it could use some refactoring since I didn't know how to refer to Count() inside the brackets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172216/how-can-i-refactor-this-c-code-using-split

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? Wouldn't this be more simple? Also I prefer `Substring` to `Split`.

```
public static string GetTextAfterMarker(string line, string marker)  {
    int pos = line.IndexOf(marker);
    if (pos == -1)
       return string.Empty;
    return line.Substring(0,pos);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the best one to me.  I can't imagine Split being more efficient than IndexOf followed by Substring.  And if you want to get really terse:  return ((pos = line.IndexOf(marker) == -1) ? string.Empty : line.Substring(0, pos);

Comment: I ran some tests on the two solutions (ran 100000 iterations of each, measuring time with Stopwatch), and found - somewhat to my surprise - that the Split-approach rather consistently worked approximately twice as fast as the IndexOf/Substring approach (and that includes the null-checks in my method). The Split approach also seem to keep its speed when given strings without the marker, a scenario that seemed to slow down the IndexOf/Substring solution.

Comment: ..and those results *really* sparked my curiosity (I found them strange), so I went to optimize both methods. If bruno's call to IndexOf is changed to `line.IndexOf(marker,0,line.Length, StringComparison.Ordinal)` it becomes significantly faster, and then the IndexOf/Substring solution wins :o)

Comment: wow... thanks for the contribution :) I'll inspect line.IndexOf(marker,0,line.Length, StringComparison.Ordinal)

Comment: A brief look at the IL for String.Split() (actually, an internal method called InternalSplitKeepEmptyENtries) indicates that String.Split() uses ordinal string comparisons.  Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions:

```
    public static string GetTextBeforeMarker(string line, string marker)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            throw new ArgumentException("line is null or empty.", "line");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(marker))
            throw new ArgumentException("marker is null or empty.", "marker");
        string EscapedMarker = Regex.Escape(marker);
        return Regex.Match(line, "([^" + EscapedMarker + "]+)" + EscapedMarker).Groups[1].Value;
    }
```

Comment: It fails on the second example in the code comments in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetTextBeforeMarker(string line, string marker)  {
    return GetTextAfterMarker(string line, string marker);
}
```